# Javascript script stops calculation prematurely on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am creating a website with big, fullscreen images, scrolling horizontally. To get the BODY width of the whole content I use a script that calculates the widths of each section used. This worked for the first 6 sections, but not for the last 2 sections.

Debugging the calculation, I recognized that the script just seems to stop after the first sections. Of course, it is inserted before the closing  tag at the end of the website.

What happens there? Can you help me? Does it have something to do with the size of the images (natural widths often between 4000-6000px)

That is an extract from my script:

```
setSectionHeight = function($windowHeight) {
    var $bodyWidth, $contentSection, $margins, $section, $sectionImage, $sectionWidth;
    $section = $("section");
    $contentSection = $('section.content');
    $sectionImage = $("section > img");
    $section.css({
      "max-height": $windowHeight - 20
    });
    $sectionImage.css({
      "max-height": $windowHeight - 20
    });
    $contentSection.css("height", $windowHeight - 80);
    $bodyWidth = 0;
    $sectionWidth = 0;
    $margins = 0;
    $section.each(function() {
      console.log("normal width: " + ($(this).width()));
      console.log("outer width " + ($(this).outerWidth()));
      $bodyWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
      return $margins += parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"));
    });
    $bodyWidth += $margins + 1;
    return setBodyWidth($bodyWidth);
  };
```

This is my basic markup used, nothing too special:

```
<section>
    <img src="#IMAGE" />
</section>
<section>
    <img src="#IMAGE" />
</section>
<section>
    <img src="#IMAGE" />
</section>
// and so on (eight times)
```

That is the whole script:

```
(function() {
  var getContentWidth, getWindowHeight, setBodyWidth, setContentWidth, setSectionHeight;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    getContentWidth();
    return getWindowHeight();
  });

  getContentWidth = function() {
    var $contentWidth;
    $contentWidth = $(window).width();
    return setContentWidth($contentWidth);
  };

  setContentWidth = function($contentWidth) {
    var $content;
    $content = $('section.content');
    return $content.css({
      "width": $contentWidth - 80
    });
  };

  getWindowHeight = function() {
    var $windowHeight;
    $windowHeight = $(window).height();
    return setSectionHeight($windowHeight);
  };

  setSectionHeight = function($windowHeight) {
    var $bodyWidth, $contentSection, $margins, $section, $sectionImage, $sectionWidth;
    $section = $("section");
    $contentSection = $('section.content');
    $sectionImage = $("section > img");
    $section.css({
      "max-height": $windowHeight - 20
    });
    $sectionImage.css({
      "max-height": $windowHeight - 20
    });
    $contentSection.css("height", $windowHeight - 80);
    $bodyWidth = 0;
    $sectionWidth = 0;
    $margins = 0;
    $section.each(function() {
      console.log("normal width: " + ($(this).width()));
      console.log("outer width " + ($(this).outerWidth()));
      $bodyWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
      return $margins += parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"));
    });
    $bodyWidth += $margins + 1;
    return setBodyWidth($bodyWidth);
  };

  setBodyWidth = function($bodyWidth) {
    return $("body").css("width", $bodyWidth);
  };

  $(window).resize(function() {
    return getWindowHeight();
  });

  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", (function() {
    return getWindowHeight();
  }), false);

}).call(this);
```

**Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: What calls your function? You've shown code that defines, but does not call, a function.

Comment: Separately: Why are you returning the result of `$margins += parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"));` from your `each` iterator? The only defined return value that function can have is `false` (meaning: stop looping).

Comment: Tested your example site: there are 9 sections and they work like a charm?

Comment: not really. have a look in the console. then refresh the browser several times – you will recognize there is sometimes arbitrary missing calculations (zero values)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the whole script involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo christophe, as your width´s are native and you are executing your calculation in a document ready bracket, it may be executed way before all images are loaded (this would explain that it only happens to last entrys and only sometime -> everytime the picture has not been loaded and your section has width= 0 then .

so if theres no other error in youre script you should be fine by changing

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    getContentWidth();
    return getWindowHeight();
  });
```

to

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    getContentWidth();
    return getWindowHeight();
  });
```

Comment: Hi John! Great point, thanks for that hint! I wasn't aware of the distinction between those two. It works now. Again: Thank you very much! :)